# g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '--cflags' g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '--libs`'

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw-w64, msys, cflags

I got these errors trying to execute mingw32-make:

`g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '--cflags' g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '--libs`'`

The makefile is the following:

```
all:
    g++ fitscli.cpp vipsoperations.cpp fits.cpp ConsoleTable.cpp `pkg-config vips-cpp --cflags --libs`  -lcfitsio -ltiff -o fitscli
```

After some research there was a suggestion to delete '--cflags' and '--libs` from the code, and I did it.

I know is that maybe the compiler g++ is not having able the options '--cflags' and '--libs`
I also tried to change to gcc compiler, but doesn´t work.

I am working on windows 11, with Msys URCT64

When I deleted the lines suggested, is causing another compilation error, so I want to know how to fix the flags issue without deleted them from the code.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your `make`'s version as well? You may be accidentally using some DOS/Windows-specific `make` instead of the one from Msys, which does not support backticks around `pkg-config`.

Comment: I installed with this command= "pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-make" and the outcome is mingw32-make.exe, that is in this folder: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin

Answer (score 2):

The backticks `` ` ` `` don't seem to work properly in `mingw32-make` (because it uses CMD as the shell, which doesn't support them).

Use `make` instead (install with `pacman -S make`), which uses Bash.

Comment: Yes, it worked, I did "ming32-make" from bash. Many thanks @HolyBlackCat

Comment: You can also set the `SHELL` makefile variable to whatever shell you want to use.  For example, `SHELL := C:/some/path/bin/bash.exe` or whatever.